# Unable to do Load Runner Scripting for .Net Desktop application

Tags: automation, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I need to test a .Net windows application using LoadRunner 12.53. Tried couple of methods but no success.

- Method1: Used .Net protocol and clicked start recording

  > Error: Start Recording Failed.

  No recording log was created. LR failed to launch the desktop application.
- Method2: Used Web Http/Html protocol.

  > Due to the below error, application cannot start 'Error:The Type initializer for (app.client.fromMainWrapper) threw an exception

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if there is any web traffic in your .NET app via a tool called Fiddler.
If yes, then use proxy recording mode of Web HTTP/HTML protocol to generate the script (Remote Application via LoadRunner proxy option in Record list).
Pcap file is another option if you just exported the traffic captured by Fiddler or Wireshark into a .pcap file and then import it into VuGen from the start recording dialog.

Answer (score 0):

1. does your application communicate across HTTP?   If not, why did you use this prototocol?
2. Let's talk about the communications architecture of your application.  Please describe the client and the next upstream architectural component that itt communicates with.  This should help to identify the types of communications protocols in play and how to automate the application effectively
3. Please take a look at the Visual Studio add-in documentation.  This will allow the developers of the .Net appliction to develop Nunit and .Net virtual users straight from the application source code.  This is the ideal development path for .Net virtual users where the source is available.